# My Tkinter photo is packed, but it shows as a blank

Tags: python, image, tkinter, png, toplevel

I can't seem to get the picture to show up on screen while having a toplevel frame on top of my main one (root). This one is just called "frame". I have circled the outline of the tkinter Frame on the included photo in this post. When I resize the picture, the green frame outline changes, but the picture itself won't show up.

I also tried to pack it on my main root window, with success, which suggests it's a toplevel window issue. I just don't know what it is. Any ideas?

Here is my code:

```
    def show_topLevelWindow():

      from tkinter import ttk
      print("Entered to show results")
      window_linkedin = Toplevel(root)
      window_linkedin.geometry('1000x590')

      frame = Frame(window_linkedin)
      frame.pack()

      error_frame = tkinter.Frame(frame, highlightbackground="green", highlightcolor="green", highlightthickness=1)

      error_label = Label(frame, text="It appears there are no results for the selected country")
      error_label.config(font=("Helvetica Neue", 20))        

      im_error = Image.open("./ressources/images_gui/aw_snap.png")
      im_error = im_error.resize((500, 500), Image.ANTIALIAS)
      im_error = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file = "./ressources/images_gui/aw_snap.png")
      im_error_label = Label(frame, image=im_error)

      try:
          if ....:
          ....unimportant code ....
          else:
              error_label.pack(in_=error_frame)            
              im_error_label.pack(in_=error_frame)  
              error_frame.pack(anchor="center")          
      except Exception as e:
          error_label.pack(in_=error_frame)            
          im_error_label.pack(in_=error_frame)            
          error_frame.pack(anchor="center")
```

[Packed image shows as blank](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XNB7d.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The single most important issue you are having is your image is not being saved for reference. if you add `global im_error` to the very top of your function your image will be visible.

That said there are some issues with your code you should correct.

First: Do not import in a function. Instead write all your imports at the top of your code.

Second: I am not sure why you are doing `.pack(in_=error_frame)`. This is not something one would ever really need. Just make sure that your label is already assigned to the correct frame. The `in_` argument is rarely used and probably most people never use it. I have been on here for two years now and this is the first time I have seen anyone use that argument.

Third: You have not shown your imports for Tkinter however based on how you have written you code it looks like you have done:

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import *
```

This is overkill and is not a good idea. Just do `import tkinter as tk` and make sure you use `tk.` prefix where it applies.

Here is your code remade:

```
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import ImageTk, Image



def show_toplevel_window():
    global im_error
    window_linkedin = tk.Toplevel(root)
    window_linkedin.geometry('1000x590')

    frame = tk.Frame(window_linkedin)
    frame.pack()

    error_frame = tk.Frame(frame, highlightbackground="green", highlightcolor="green", highlightthickness=1)
    error_frame.pack()

    error_label = tk.Label(frame, font=("Helvetica Neue", 20), text="It appears there are no results for the selected country")
    error_label.pack()  

    im_error = Image.open("./ressources/images_gui/aw_snap.png")
    im_error = im_error.resize((500, 500), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    im_error = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file = "./ressources/images_gui/aw_snap.png")
    im_error_label = tk.Label(error_frame, image=im_error)
    im_error_label.pack()

root = tk.Tk()
show_toplevel_window()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you!! For the solution and your kind tips :-)

Comment: @JUANRUIZDEBUSTILLO glad to help.